# How do I retrieve an Excel cell value in VBA as formatted in the WorkSheet?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I need to keep leading zeros on a list of numbers. The numbers are added like this (in a loop, but this is just an example using the (1, 1):

```
Set cel = Sheet.worksh.Cells(1, 1)
cel.ColumnWidth = 10
cel.Value = e.Name
cel.NumberFormat = "0000"
```

Where `e.Name` is the number, something like "0720". This displays on the worksheet just fine, but if I do something like this:

```
Msgbox Sheet.worksh.Cells(1, 1).Value
```

I get "720". I need it to be "0720", I know I could check using `Len()` and add the zeros that way, but I was wondering if there was a more direct approach with the Range object that would do this for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use This:

```
Msgbox Format(Sheet.worksh.Cells(1,1).Value, "0000")
```

Answer (score 28):

You are confusing a number with its textual representation.

You want the `.Text` property, not `.Value`, but then, [you might have problems with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470263/excel-is-calculating-a-formula-with-a-vba-function-as-an-error-unless-it-is-re-en).

Comment: Careful with the text property. If the cell looks like this "####" that's what it is going to shoot back to you. It's safer to use Lance Roberts' method. Just a warning from experience.

Comment: If the circumstances allow you could add `Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit` before calling `.Text` method on a cell.

Answer (score 8):

Even better, if you're not sure what the format is:

Msgbox Format(Sheet.worksh.Cells(1,1).Value, Sheet.worksh.Cells(1,1).NumberFormat)

Comment: This doesn't work as expected if the NumberFormat is General--when calling Format("397","General") you get "Ge0eral" as your result.

Comment: Is the problem that 397 is provided to Format() as text, not a number?

Comment: @nvuono Just add an if statement for General (also, "Ge0eral"? You sure you didn't spell it wrong?)

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but you could always try calling up the value and number format separately, like this:

> Msgbox Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Sheet.worksh.Cells(1,
>   1).Value, Sheet.worksh.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat)