# How to format copied content from excel to PowerPoint? (Shape and Table Cell)

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, powerpoint, shapes

I have used VBA to copy values from Excel cells into table cells (tablename: "myTable", 2*2) and also into text for shapes (shape name "Oval11"). Now I want to format these as follows in PowerPoint using VBA from Excel:

- Make numbers as % with 0 decimal places (existing formatting in Excel)
  -If number<0%, color the cell or shape red and if number>0%, color the shape or cell green

How can this be done?

I am using Office 2010, but compatibility with Office 2007 will also be helpful.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your excel sheet is already formatted as you want it in the PowerPoint, when copying the contents of those cells use `.Text` instead of `.Value`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932901/how-do-i-retrieve-an-excel-cell-value-in-vba-as-formatted-in-the-worksheet) for more details on how it works.

If your excel sheet is not formatted properly, you can either create a string variable in vba from the value and format it within vba, or format it using the `=TEXT()` command in excel through VBA, and store the result as a string.

Comment: Thanks...it worked..since I just needed to copy data already formatted in Excel :)