# Excel VBA: Looping Though Cells In ActiveSheet

Tags: vba, loops, excel, cells

I'm trying to loop through a specified number of cells (defined by width and height), but I'm running into problems here. It keeps stalling on me, and then gets upset about:

```
If .Cells(11 + row, col).Value > maxVal Then
```

It's giving me an "Application defined or object defined error"

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with my code:

```
Sub ApplyFilter()

    Dim maxVal As Double
    Dim minVal As Double

    maxVal = ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value
    minVal = ActiveSheet.Range("D11").Value

    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer

    width = ActiveSheet.Range("L3").Value
    height = ActiveSheet.Range("L4").Value


    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    ActiveSheet.Select
    With Selection
        row = 1
        Do
            col = 1
            Do

                If .Cells(11 + row, col).Value > maxVal Then
                    .Cells(11 + row, col).Value = 0
                End If
                If .Cells(11 + row, col).Value < minVal Then
                     .Cells(11 + row, col).Value = 0
                End If
                col = col + 1
                width = width - 1
            Loop Until width = 1
            row = row + 1
            height = height - 1
        Loop Until height = 1
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: There's no cell with column=0.  You should be starting at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Excel would give "Application defined or object defined error" for no reason, [because it's just the way Excel is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470263/excel-is-calculating-a-formula-with-a-vba-function-as-an-error-unless-it-is-re-e), but that's probably not the case here.

Don't use `Select` or `Selection` to interact with objects. Name the objects directly.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
  ...
End With
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that, but it's still giving me that same (perhaps random) error on the same line.

Comment: @user1588214 What values do `row` and `col` have at that point?

Comment: col (which is now called 'j') is apparently causing the problem. It's over 16,000 when it should stop at 479 for each row in this case. Width has its negative value, -16,000 +

Comment: Tested the value for width, it gets its initial value (480) correctly.

Comment: Ah, I need to reset width in the loop when row is incremented. Dur. That was the problem. Well I feel smart.

Comment: I'd like to add that I should have used a For loop here instead. It would have avoided the problem altogether, as this is what it's intended for.

Comment: @FancyCorndog In this case rather than accept suggestion as the answer - which it didn't eventuate as - you can post your self solution as a separate answer, or as an edit to your initial question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here was that I was not resetting the width value for each new row. I should have been using a For loop, which would have handled the problem more intuitively.