# Excel VBA function works in Visual Basic, but fails in Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a 2D array of data using "CurrentRegion".

```
Function ProcessData()
Dim dataList()
dataList = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
' TODO Process the dataList
End Function
```

When I test this within Visual Basic (Run/F5), it works great; my dataList is built with no problems. However, if I set a cell in my worksheet to:

```
= ProcessData()
```

the function silently fails at the "CurrentRegion" step. Why does this happen? How do I remedy it?

Comment: Do you have to use CurrentRegion? Can you perhaps find the last cell using built-in functions?

Comment: I suppose I will have to pass the region to the function as a parameter.

Comment: You can also try an array function to return an array. Something like TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE("A1:B5"))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call a Function from an Excel cell (i.e. as an User-Defined-Function/UDF), you can only access the ranges that are handed to the function via parameters. Any access to other ranges (and `.CurrentRegion` is a range) will result in a "Circular Reference" potential cancellation of the execution.

Also, in a UDF you cannot modify anything on the worksheet - but only return the result of function!

For further details, check out this [link](http://www.excel-it.com/UDF.htm).

Comment: So a function when called from a Subroutine **is** able to manipulate sheet/cell values (probably a bad practice) whereas a function called from the Worksheet is not?

Comment: @DavidZemens: I was referring to a UDF, i.e. a VBA function that is called from a formula. This function is not allowed to modify the worksheet in any way, nor interact with the user - but only compute the a result based on the input parameters. A sub called from a worksheet (e.g. via a button or event) however can modify the worksheet. This is not "bad practice")

Comment: Right. I'm asking about the difference between a UDF formula called form the worksheet, and a VBA function called from within a subroutine (perhaps invoked from a button, etc). The latter can manipulate worksheet cells. Is doing so a bad habit? Seems to me like it might be.

Comment: @DavidZemens: Ah, I see. Yes, when a function is called from anything but a UDF, you can manipulate the workbook. and yes, I'd consider this not best practice, as a function should do some kind of calculation only IMHO.

Comment: First paragraph is entirely wrong. Functions called from sheet are free to access any ranges in any sheets ([subject to some bugs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6471943/11683)), as long as they don't modify them.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this Q&A having the same problem. I think there is a kind of bug for using `CurrentRegion` within UDF and the reason is not as Peter suggest in his answer.

Compare these two function:

```
Function GetAddressOfColumn(TopCell As Range)
    GetAddressOfColumn = TopCell.CurrentRegion.Address
End Function


Function GetAddressOfColumnOK(TopCell As Range)
    GetAddressOfColumnOK = Range(TopCell, TopCell.End(xlDown)).Address
End Function
```

Both function use different kind of range references. If Peter were right both should return false result. So, look at the data range below and the result of both function. As you can see second function result is as expected and correct.

[image]

Comment: Interesting indeed, but not an answer to the Q. To Peter's point, you can certainly *access* some properties and methods of range objects which are *not* passed to the function parameters (e.g., you could return `Range("B3").Address` and that will not fail.  But you are right, the `CurrentRegion` seems to be returning unexpected results!