# How to write data into cells in VBA with run time locations?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user defined function in VBA, which write the some Data calculated by a Function. The location to write data will be the row-cells next to "cell" where user calls the VBA function in Excel sheet.

ex:
consider printing a multiplication table for a number Given by user

```
Public function Mul_Table(number as integer)
   dim wb as string
   dim ws as string
   dim i as integer ,row_num as integer,column_num as integer 
   wb= activeworkbook.name
   ws=activesheet.name
   row_num = activecell.row
   column_num =activecell.column
   for i = 1 to 20
        workbooks(wb).sheets(ws).cells(row_num+i , column_num).value = i*number
   next i
end function
```

Now when I executed I got problem as #value error in the cell where the function is called.
In debugging, the controller is throwing an error at line                                       "`workbooks(wb).sheets(ws).cell(row_num+i , column_num) = i*number`" 
but I am not able to find why it is going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA function works in Visual Basic, but fails in Worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646887/excel-vba-function-works-in-visual-basic-but-fails-in-worksheet)

Answer (score 2):

> The location to write data will be the row-cells next to "cell" where user calls the VBA function in excel sheet .

This cannot be done with a User-defined function, called from the worksheet.  That is why you're getting the `#Value!` error returned.

A *function* by definition is designed to *return a value* to the cell wherein the function resides. It should not be used to attempt to alter *other* cells.

If you breakpoint and step through you're code, you'll observe that it will abort probably on this line, if not sooner:

```
workbooks(wb).sheets(ws).cells(row_num+i , column_num).value = i*number
```

The reason for this, generally speaking, is that a UDF called from the worksheet is not permitted to manipulate any range objects (or properties of range objects) which are not explicitly passed as an argument to the function. This is to prevent circular errors, infinite loops, etc.

Make it a `Sub` instead of a function, and it should work:

```
Public Sub Mul_Table()
   dim number as INteger

   dim wb as string
   dim ws as string
   dim i as integer ,row_num as integer,column_num as integer 

   number = Application.InputBox("Enter an integer value")
   wb= activeworkbook.name
   ws=activesheet.name
   row_num = activecell.row
   column_num =activecell.column
   for i = 1 to 20
        workbooks(wb).sheets(ws).cells(row_num+i , column_num).value = i*number
   next i
End Sub
```

Comment: great answer, finally some good explanation of the limitations of Functions. My question is : Can he make it so, that the UDF is entered into cell and inside the UDF, there is a call to the sub you provided, but with the argument already passed into the function, as OP originally wanted? So the sequence then looks like `function Mul_Table(number as integer)` then `call Sub Mul_Table_other()...code...code...end sub` then `End function`.

Comment: @BranislavKollár Why not try that and see what happens? If that doesn't work, there are possible workarounds using `Application.Evaluate` which you can find here on StackOverflow, but I would not recommend trying to override these limitations. They're in place for a (good) reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646887/excel-vba-function-works-in-visual-basic-but-fails-in-worksheet/15647054#15647054

Comment: Just to finish my theory. It does NOT work. The code just stops (exits) at the assignment line inside the loop, with `i = 1` even inside called sub. And thanks for the tip and link!

Comment: That's what I suspected, because the `Function` call still has priority in the call stack, so any subroutines called from that function would be subject to same limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a function or sub routine to do this. You can add a button or shortcut to excel to run your code. I would like to make your code more optimized.

1. Sub routine to generate multiplication table.

   ```
   Public Sub Mul_Table(number As Integer)
      Dim i, row_num, column_num As Integer
      For i = 1 To 20
          ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = i & " x " & number & " = " & i * number
          'ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1).Value = i * number 'Uncomment if you want the result in a new column
      Next
   End Sub
   ```
2. Sub routine that generate multiplication table based on user input.

   ```
   Sub getMultiplicationTable()
      mynumber = InputBox("Enter the number.", "Enter number")
      Call Mul_Table(CInt(mynumber))
   End Sub
   ```
3. Sub routine that generates multiplication table of 2

   ```
   Sub getMultiplicationTableOfTwo()
      Call Mul_Table(2)
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing, you could using the worksheet_change event which will fire when something is entered, you can then have the code check the address of target (Target.Address) to see if they entered the data where you want, if so then perform your task.

Here is an example I just knocked up for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim X As Long
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For X = 1 To 20
        Range("B" & X).Value = Range("A1").Value * X
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Drop that in the VBE at the worksheet level and then enter a number in A1.

There is a number of other ways you can do this, you can post the entire range in one go rather than looping through (I left the looping as you said you are learning and this is how you have tried to do it)

There is no error checking in there or anything but I am sure you could figure that part out based on what criteria you want.

Alternatively you can do this with formulas something like in B1:

```
=$A$1*ROW(B1)
```

Then drag down and put a number in A1