# #VALUE error when copying sheets

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, udf

I´m using a UDF that is basically a vlookup simplified. Here´s the code:

```
Function SUELDOBASICO(Columna As Integer) As Double

SUELDOBASICO = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Application.Caller.Parent.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 3), Application.Caller.Parent.Parent.Sheets("Escalas Salariales").Range("A3:DJ23"), Columna, False)

End Function
```

I´ve noticed that sometimes when copying sheets(within the same workbook), I get a `#VALUE` error. If I "edit" the cell in Excel, changing nothing, just using `F2` and `Enter`, the error disappears. It used to happen when simply changing windows (to Firefox, and back to Excel, for instance). That´s why I used `Caller` and `Parent` so much in the code. It is almost completely fixed, except when copying sheets sometimes. I can´t seem to find the source of the error.
Help please.

Comment: My gut says that when you copy sheets, perhaps you are changing workbooks? So that above, you refer to Sheets("Escalas Salariales").Range... but really you should say Workbooks("WorkbookName.xlsx").Sheets("Escalas...

Comment: I´m not copying to another workbook. It´s within the same workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't your exact question, but, if at all possible, I would suggest to just avoid VBA completely if that's at all an option and write your formula as follows:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()),'Escalas Salariales'!$A$3:$DJ$23,XXXXX,false)
```

and `XXXXX` can be the same as your `Columna` variable currently.

That would guarantee your code to work as needed.

---

Given what was discussed in the comments and trying my absolute best to ensure this works, I actually don't see anything wrong with your code and am just GUESSING it may have something to do with `Application.Caller`.

When this kind of thing happens to me, I try my best to just use the debugger to figure out why - That usually involves either `Stop` statements to be able to step into code and see what happened or `Debug.Print Err.Description` kind of messages.

Either way, I tried to break each part down, so, at the very least you can see where the issue comes from.
To do so, I re-worked your function (with some major overkill)....

```
Function SUELDOBASICO(Columna As Integer) As Double

On Error GoTo ErrorCheck

Dim CellRef As Range
Dim LookupRef As Range

    Set CellRef = Cells(Application.Caller.Range("A1").Row, 3)
    Set LookupRef = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Sheets("Escalas Salariales").Range("A3:DJ23")

    SUELDOBASICO = Application.VLookup(CellRef, LookupRef, Columna, False)

    Exit Function

ErrorCheck:
    Stop
    Resume

End Function
```

(Also note that I changed `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to `Application.VLookup` - Look at [this link](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/) for an explanation)

Once you figure it out, I would, though, remove the error code from the function as that isn't a good idea for production code - Just for Debugging.

Hopefully that can give you the answers you are looking for.

Hope that helps....

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Taking into account the possibility that copying the sheet is causing this error, here's a test to see if the process gets fixed:

```
Function SUELDOBASICO(Columna As Integer) As Double

On Error GoTo ErrorCheck

Dim NumTimesErrored As Integer
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim WaitSeconds As Integer
NumTimesErrored = 0

Dim CellRef As Range
Dim LookupRef As Range

    Set CellRef = Cells(Application.Caller.Range("A1").Row, 3)
    Set LookupRef = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Sheets("Escalas Salariales").Range("A3:DJ23")

    SUELDOBASICO = Application.VLookup(CellRef, LookupRef, Columna, False)

    Exit Function

ErrorCheck:
    ' This will make it tries this "hack" up to 3 times:
    If NumTimesErrored < 3 Then
        StartTime = Now
        WaitSeconds = 1 ' Wait one second
        Loop While Now - TimeStart < TimeSerial(0, 0, WaitSeconds)
            DoEvents ' Allows all the other processes to complete
        Loop
        ' Increment the number of times you've tried this:
        NumTimesErrored = NumTimesErrored + 1
        ' Go back to the calculation step that errored
        Resume
    End If

    Stop
    Resume

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in another answer, I´m trying to make the formula shorter, that´s why I made the UDF.

Comment: @SantiagoSettecasi, Did you look at / consider Grade Eh Bacon's comment - That makes the most amount of sense to me.... If that's not the case let me know and I'll look into posting a different solution....

Comment: I have considered it. I´m copying the sheet to the same workbook, not a different one.

Comment: @SantiagoSettecasi, I edited my answer with something new that may at least help point you in the right direction as to why this is happening - Hope it helps....

Comment: Thanks. I must admit that I know very little about VBA, but I´m Trying to learn. I added the line Debug.Print Err.Description before the Stop instruction. What I get in the inmediate window is "subindex out of interval". What could that be?

Comment: @SantiagoSettecasi, try using `Application.VLookup` rather than `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` - It may fix the probem completely, or, at the very least, it will give you a more logical error - I'm going to update my code to that too as that makes more sense anyways.....

Comment: I´ve tried everything you suggest, but still no solution. I´ve been able to identify where the problem lies:  If I add the line `Debug.Print Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Sheets(2).Range("A3:DJ23").Count` after the `set CellRef` line, I get the count when It´s working properly, and just an empty string when I copy the sheet. If I were to edit the cell with the UDF and press enter again, everything works ok and I get the count, as mentioned earlier. Any new suggestions?  Thank you very much.

Comment: The easiest solution I can think of is **if you are going to always have this function in the same workbook that calls it**, you no longer need the `Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent` part which I'm sure is causing the issue - You can replace it with `ThisWorkbook` or just nothing... Let me know and we'll move forward from there....

Comment: Unfortunately I´m not. The UDF is in a module of an add-in. I use the UDF in multiple workbooks.

Comment: I´d like to add that I´ve also tried adding the line `Debug.Print Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Sheets(2).Name` and it works correctly until that point, giving "ESCALAS SALARIALES". It seems that the `Range` part has some minor problem when copying sheets.

Comment: Ok, I **THINK** I know what your problem is, then.... In copying over the worksheet, it's probably trying to re-calculate the cells before the copy is complete and, therefore, messing up the  it's messing up the `Application.Caller` portion... I'll come up with a "hack" to test this and let me know if it works....

Comment: I think I´m having the same problem as in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470263/excel-is-calculating-a-formula-with-a-vba-function-as-an-error-unless-it-is-re-e?rq=1). However, I don´t know how to apply a solution to my particular problem. What do you think?

Comment: Yup, same issue - It's what I commented on above... Busy today, but will post an update to my answer above....

Comment: @SantiagoSettecasi, I posted up new code - I didn't test it because I'm pretty busy today, but it should work for testing the hypothesis... Give it a try.

Comment: Ok, a few comments: 1 - I think there was a small error in the code. I had to change `Loop While` for `Do While`. 2 - Unfortunately it´s not fixing the problem. The code keeps reaching the line `Stop`. 3 - I tried changing `NumTimesErrored < 3` and `WaitSeconds = 1`to 10 and 60 and I keep reaching `Stop`.

Comment: Well, I´ve tried a lot of things and nothing worked. Luckily the las thing I tried was adding `Application.Volatile` and THAT somehow seemed to do the trick. I don´t know why but it works. I´m leaving this here for anyone with the same problem, or for someone to explain to me why this happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The is no need to use caller and parent.

```
Function SUELDOBASICO(Cell as Range, LookupRange as range, Columna As Integer) As Double

' When you call the function :
' set Cell to be  the cell in column C in the same row

' Set LookupRange to Sheets("Escalas Salariales").Range("$A$3:$DJ$23")

SUELDOBASICO =     Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell, LookupRange, Columna, False)
End Function
```

example of formula in a cell...

=SUELDOBASICO(C10,'Escalas Salariales'!$A$3:$DJ$23)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I made the UDF with only one variable to be able to type it fast. There´s really just one variable here(Columna). I know I could use a name for the range but still, I´m disinclined to use that for the same reason. Also, I´m curious as to why this error occurs.