# VBA Function gives #VALUE! error when used as Formula in Excel, whereas works fine in debugging mode

Tags: excel, vba

I have written following Excel VBA code for **Function** to get the **count of cells with *Green fill*** in a Range.

It gives *#VALUE! error* when I use this Function as Formula, e.g., `=GreenCount(E3:E48)`, in Excel.

```
Function GreenCount(rcell As Range) As Long

    Dim myCell As Range
    GreenCount = 0
   
    For Each myCell In rcell

       If myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
           GreenCount = GreenCount + 1
       End If
        
    Next myCell

End Function
```

Surprisingly, desired result is seen in debugging mode when the Function is called through below Sub.

```
Sub Find_Count()

Dim rcell As Range
    
Set rcell = Sheet2.Range("E3:E48")
Sheet2.Range("E49").Value = GreenCount(rcell)

End Sub
```

Any help to sort out the error would be highly appreciated.

Edit: Cells in the Range are conditionally formatted.

Comment: It [doesn't want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6471943/11683) to give you `myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` from a sheet function. It can give you `myCell.Interior.Color` if you like.

Comment: In case of Conditionally formatted cells ```myCell.Interior.Color``` is not working.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat

Comment: It's even documented there! Good to know; it isn't documented for `Text`.

Comment: Why don't you use the formula that makes the cells green instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a workaround by calling your function indirectly, using the `Evaluate` method.

```
Function EGreenCount(rcell As Range) As Long
    EGreenCount = rcell.Parent.Evaluate("GreenCount(" & rcell.Address & ")")
End Function
```

Comment: Yes you can, and then you can [enjoy a fresh start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698777/excel-office-365-restarts-automatically-while-executing-udf#comment92324771_52698777).

Comment: In that example, the function changed the contents of the cells, but here it only reads.

Comment: @MGonet as you rightly said, my requirement was just to read the data from reference range & your solution works perfectly. Appreciate.

Comment: I have even tried it where a sample UDF is required to change/update content in other Cells. It works there as well. However, I need to check if heavy data file sustains ```Evaluate``` method.