# How to concatenate string with DATE()?

Tags: excel

In Excel, I'm trying to have a cell look something like:

`by no later than August 27, 2012`

When I try to concatenate a string with a `DATE`, for example:

`="by no later than " & DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))`

I get an output like this:

`by no later than 41118`

How can I get a date to show up instead of an integer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DATE` builds a date timestamp. You need to convert that to a string. See this question for how to do so:

- [Excel Date to String conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636157/excel-date-to-string-conversion)

It would look something like this:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't really need DATE function at all for today's date, you could use just

`="by no later than "&TEXT(TODAY(),"mmmm d, yyyy")`

Comment: I was just using it as an example. I'm not actually using `TODAY`.

Comment: Ah.....OK, took you a little too literally......

Answer (score -3):

If you format the cell containing your number `(41118)` as `Date`, you'll get exactly 27.8.2012. Simple!

Comment: Then you can't put text in the cell.