# Excel concatenate cell values from cells of different types

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet where I'm unable to concatenate a line to group the cells together. In my spreadsheet I input dates and times to auto-add hours (a schedule with daily start/stop times). I'm trying to find a way to string these together to insert the lines into a Word doc.

Excel:  (* indicates formula/calculation)

|  DATE   |  START  |   STOP  | Total*| Day* | ddd* |

| 2/27/23 | 8:00 AM | 7:00 PM |  11   |  Mon | 2/27 |

I've tried using =text() and =value() but nothing seems to get me the information I need in a string. I do not want to do a copy/paste - the idea is to input the data once, and have another sheet read that in to a chart that can be inserted in to Word. What am I missing..?

```
=CONCATENATE(Rates!I9," ",Rates!H9," from ",Rates!C9," to ",Rates!D9)
```

I was expecting:
Mon 2/27 from 8:00 AM to 7:00 PM

I'm getting:
Mon 44984 from 0.333333333333333 to 0.895833333333333

Comment: Dates are represented in Excel as positive integer and the time portion as the decimal part of that number. That is why you are getting that output. Please provide a sample data so we can understand better the input and the expected output.

Comment: We need to use the `TEXT()` function to format the date and the time when we are combining. The `TEXT()` function allows us to modify the cell-based format to our requirements, this is because dates & times are stored as double/numbers in Excel, so that said, the integer part represents the Date while the decimal part is the time.

Comment: Have you tried searching the `Stackoverflow` certainly there are ample of examples, one such is this one [Using TEXT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336518/concatenating-date-with-a-string-in-excel) & here as well [Microsoft_Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/combine-text-with-a-date-or-time-cef6a66c-8176-470c-ba85-4b030405dfbf)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. Let's generate in `A2` a timestamp via `NOW()` function, and in `B2` two hours after `NOW() + 2/24`. Then in `C2` you can build the following output as follow:

```
=CONCAT(TEXT(A2, "ddd mm/dd"), " from ", 
 TEXT(A2-TRUNC(A2), "hh:mm AM/PM"), " to ",  
 TEXT(B2-TRUNC(B2), "hh:mm AM/PM"))
```

**Note**: Dates in excel are represented as a Whole number and the time is the decimal part of that number. The first hour is represented as `1/24`.

Or you can create a user `LAMBDA` function to get the decimal part (`GETDEC`) to simplify it:

```
=LET(GETDEC, LAMBDA(x, x-TRUNC(x)), CONCAT(TEXT(A2, "ddd mm/dd"), " from ",
 TEXT(GETDEC(A2), "hh:mm AM/PM"), " to ",  TEXT(GETDEC(B2), "hh:mm AM/PM")))
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample output file]

or just putting it all together in a user `LAMBDA` function (`GET_TIME_INFO`) that can be used inside a `LET` function:

```
=LET(GET_TIME_INFO, LAMBDA(a,b, LET(GETDEC, LAMBDA(x, x-TRUNC(x)),
 CONCAT(TEXT(a, "ddd mm/dd"), " from ",
  TEXT(GETDEC(a), "hh:mm AM/PM"), " to ",  TEXT(GETDEC(b), "hh:mm AM/PM"))
 )), GET_TIME_INFO(A2,B2)
)
```

or you can define it in Name Manager and just use it, like any other regular Excel function: `GET_TIME_INFO(A2,B2)`.